# PHP - upload files [POST]

Tags: php, forms, post, file-upload, upload

I have an e-mail form here in PHP. With text, ale other fields everything works fine. The problem is with uploading the file.
Everything looks good for me. Even with the function for the file e-mails are perfectly sended. But there isn`t any attachement in the message.
When I click "Wyślij wiadomość" (Send) I have a message about a problem with uploading the file.
Does enyone know what goes wrong?

```html
<?php
//--- początek formularza ---
if(empty($_POST['submit'])) {
?>

      <form action="" method="post">
                        <table class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col-md-2">NAZWISKO:<br /><br/></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="formName" /></td>
                            </tr>
   <tr>
                            <td class="col-md-2">E-MAIL:<br /><br/></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="formEmail"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-md-2">ZAŁĄCZ KOSZTORYS:<br /><br/></td>
                            <td><input type="file" name="formFile" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="formularzTresc col-md-2">TREŚĆ:<br /><br/></td>
                            <td><textarea name="formText"></textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><p align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Wyślij wiadomość" /><p></td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
<?php
} else {

//dane adresata
$email = '#';

//dane z formularza
$formName = $_POST['formName'];
$formEmail = $_POST['formEmail'];
$formText = $_POST['formText'];
$formFile = $_POST['formFile'];

if(!empty($formName) && !empty($formEmail) && !empty($formText)) {

//--- początek funkcji weryfikującej adres e-mail ---
function checkMail($checkmail) {
  if(filter_var($checkmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    if(checkdnsrr(array_pop(explode("@",$checkmail)),"MX")){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
//--- koniec funkcji ---
if(checkMail($formEmail)) {
  //dodatkowe informacje: ip i host użytkownika
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $host = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
 
  //tworzymy szkielet wiadomości
  //treść wiadomości
  $mailText = "Treść wiadomości:\n$formText\nOd: $formName, $formEmail, $formFile ($ip, $host)";
 
  //adres zwrotny
  $mailHeader = "From: $formName <$formEmail>\r\n";
 $mailHeader .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";

        $target_path = "../przeslanePliki";
        $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['formFile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['formFile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['formFile']['name']). 
    "Plik został wysłany";
        
} else{
    echo "Wystąpił problem z przesłaniem pliku. Prosimy spróbować ponownie.";
}
 
  //funkcja odpowiedzialna za wysłanie e-maila
  @mail($email, 'Pytanie do eksperta', $mailText, $mailHeader) or die('Błąd: wiadomość nie została wysłana');
 
  //komunikat o poprawnym wysłaniu wiadomości
  echo 'Wiadomość została wysłana';
} else {
  echo 'Adres e-mail jest niepoprawny';
}

} else {
  //komunikat w przypadku nie powodzenia
  echo 'Wypełnij wszystkie pola formularza';
}

//--- koniec formularza ---
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the *exact* error message?

Comment: I dodn`t know, I don`t know how to write logs to the file or sth.
I know that the else section here worked:
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['formFile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
But thank to the man below I fixed this problem, but there`s a new one now if works fine, there`s an information that file has been sent but no attachement in my mailbox just a text message without it.

Answer (score 1):

The form also needs the following attribute: enctype="multipart/form-data". It specifies which content-type to use when submitting the form

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: OK, now I have an information that file has been sent, but there`s no attachement in the message in my mailbox :/

Comment: you change $formFile = $_POST['formFile']; to $formFile = $_FILES['formFile'];

Comment: I`ve changed it but still doesn`t work. E-mail is sent but nothing attached.